# Jetpack BottomNavigationView How to remove content fade in animation

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm creating a single activity applicatition. Inside Activity there is a `BottomNavigationView` 
with `NavHostFragment`. Bottom navigation view comprise of multiple menu items.

For easy to explain lets say there are three fragments `"FragmentOne"`, `"FragmentTwo"`, `"FragmentThree"`

each fragment have a different Toolbar. As a example `"FragmentOne"` is haveing a Toolbar with `CollapingToolbarLayout`, and `"FragmentTwo"` has a Normal Toolbar Design and `"FragmentThree"` has a toolbar with Image.

I have included different design Toolbars in each fragment and the BottomNavigationView is inside Activity.

Where select each bottom navigation menu, fragments are navigating correctly but content is showing fade in animation/transition.

I have set the app theme as `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` So now since Toolbar is also inside the fragment content area `Toolbar` also showing fade in transition.I'm okay with content transition but Toolbar should stay Solid.

Kindly help to me to solve this and feel free to request more information.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: @ElJazouli No bro. I didn't find any solution to get rid of it. I think it's the default. So what I did to fulfill my requirement is, I chose the old way and not follow the navigation component.